# Can I fly a paramotor after learning on a paraglider?

Tags: safety, flight-training, paraglider

[This video](https://youtu.be/rvQ9DjJNal0) has inspired me to spend next week doing a 6 day paragliding course. The only downside is the school near me don't teach paramotoring.

***Could I buy (and safely use/self-teach) a paramotor after learning to paraglide?***

Comment: Are you asking about the legality of flying a paramotor after doing this course or about how safe that would be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's never safe to teach oneself to fly *anything*. Aviation pioneers did that out of necessity, but many died or got badly hurt doing it. Training gives you the benefit of decades of hard-won experience without the underpants soiling moments and broken bones.

You are talking about going from being an inexperienced paraglider pilot to a complete novice powered paramotor pilot without the benefit of any mentoring or coaching.

It's a **bad idea™**

Comment: A friend of mine who was a private pilot SEL flew a Powered Parachute (the thing w/ a seat and wheels) w/ no training other than a few minutes of instruction from the owner.  He survived.

Comment: He had instruction then @quietflyer

Comment: True, also it was a bad idea in my opinion

Comment: I agree @quietflyer, a tandem lesson or two would have been a good idea!

Comment: @quietflyer, he still had a general flight training, and was probably fortunate not to encounter any of the paraglider-specific issues like collapse. Most of the training, for any flying machine, is about how to handle various failures, and paragliders have their specific failure modes.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. There is a reason it is strongly recommended to do a conversion course.

As a paraglider pilot your skillset is focussed on very different aspects to the most important skills for paramotoring. You may be good at ridge soaring or thermally or XC or strong wind launches for coastal flying. Almost none of these skills are relevant to most paramotor aviation.

The following is an example of some of the things you should learn before flying paramotors that you will not have covered before as a freeflight paraglider:

- **Safety** - both in terms of prop safety, both on the ground and in the air as well as pre-flight checks, maintenance, fuel/fire safety, ear defenders, ground starting.
- **Theory of flight** - things like reflex profiles, trimmers, hang points, torque, how throttle power affects pitch/angle of attack, etc.
- **Motor** - in addition to maintenance and safety issues, things like storage and transport, breaking engines in, oil ratios, fuel types, assembly, repair, types and sizes of prop.
- **Launch/landing** - powered launches are very different and you'll have to learn to taxi, to ground handle with a heavy engine on your back, a completely different body position for launching, again torque effects while taxiing, how best to abort launches, how to avoid burning your wing on a hot exhaust or getting lines caught in an idling prop.
- **Airspace, navigation and comms** become a much larger facts in powered flights.

And of course many other aspects.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. In terms of flying skills, assuming you’re a good paraglider pilot you already have the prerequisite skill to fly paramotor. The only thing you’re missing is ground school in air law and weather. And in some countries (not the US) you are required to have license and registration. Sounds funny but is true.